# Is there value in generating boolean arrays prior to sub-selection with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization

Curious if, when making a sub-selection in Pandas, pre-generating the boolean Numpy array is in any way advantageous.

Without being very familiar with how Pandas and Numpy handle these kinds of queries, I wonder if calculating them all at once (example method 1) within the subselection query might somehow involve more resources than if each array were measured in an isolated way (example method 2).

In particular, I wonder if this would be a problem/exacerbated if you were doing a number of queries, as in the below example/s.

Example method 1:

```
df.loc[
    (df['foo'] >= df['bar']) &
    (df['foo'] < df['baz']) &
    (df['den'] >= df['dog']) &
    (df['den'] < df['lan']) &
    (df['loo'] > df['foo']) &
    (df['loo'] <= df['baz']) &
    (df['ban'] >= df['raw']) &
    (df['ban'] < df['baz']),
    'very_special_col'] = another_new_calc
```

Example method 2:

```
def_a = (df['foo'] >= df['bar'])
def_b = (df['foo'] < df['baz'])
def_c = (df['den'] >= df['dog'])
def_d = (df['den'] < df['lan'])
def_e = (df['loo'] > df['foo'])
def_f = (df['loo'] <= df['baz'])
def_g = (df['ban'] >= df['raw'])
def_h = (df['ban'] < df['baz'])

all_checks_a_go = (def_a,
                   def_b,
                   def_c,
                   def_d,
                   def_e,
                   def_f,
                   def_g,
                   def_h)

df.loc[all_checks_a_go, 'very_special_col'] = another_new_calc
```

Update:
Also, please see @piRSquared's response, as well as my comment beneath it. In it, I acknowledge that assembling the booleans incrementally might also be another possible way to make this operation even more performant (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a difference in the two ways you've done it.  However, you can write one boolean array and keep overwriting it

```
mask = (df['foo'] >= df['bar'])
mask = (df['foo'] <  df['baz']) & mask
mask = (df['den'] >= df['dog']) & mask
# ... etc

df.loc[mask, 'very_special_col'] = another_new_calc
```

Or you can use `eval`

```
q = ' & '.join([
        'foo >= bar',
        'foo < baz',
        'den >= dog',
        'den < lan',
        'loo > foo',
        'loo <= baz',
        'ban >= raw',
        'ban < baz'
    ])
df.loc[df.eval(q), 'very_special_col'] = another_new_calc
```

---

**Interesting Results**
*Consider the dataframe `df`*

```
import numexpr as ne
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([True, False], (1000000, 8)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

%timeit df.eval('A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H')
%timeit df.eval('((A & B) & (C & D)) & ((E & F) & (G & H))')
%timeit A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H = (v for k, v in df.items()); A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H
%timeit A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H = (v for k, v in df.items()); ne.evaluate('A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H')
%timeit A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H = [df[c].values for c in df]; ne.evaluate('A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H')
%timeit (((A & B) & (C & D)) & ((E & F) & (G & H)))
%timeit df.all(1)
%timeit pd.Series(df.values.all(1), df.index)

100 loops, best of 3: 6.89 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.71 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.85 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.91 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 16.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 19.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess my thought was that, in example 2, each individual boolean was evaluated independently. I wonder if there is value in evaluating each outside of the dataframe selection operation - as if that might somehow reduce the complexity of the operation. I appreciate also the incremental assembly of the boolean/s in your example.

Comment: No, every independent one is generating a pandas series object with a complete index and set of values.  You do this in both example one or two.  The only advantage I offer is to not waste the memory resource by overwriting each time.  However, it may likely be less performant.  You could also to the same thing via the `values` attribute which will avoid the creation of a pandas series each time and limit it to just the boolean array.  That would look like `mask = df['foo'].values >= df['bar'].values` and etc...

Comment: The complexity of the operation doesn't change as each `&` is a binary operation that gets resolved by oder of operations.